# Convert from bin to int/char without loosing leading "0"

Tags: python, int, bin

Is there anyway that

```
>>> int('0000001',2)
1
```

Could save the leading 0s ?

What I want to do is, with a huge string of bits, in 8 and 8 bits I would convert to int, and then to char, and write it all in a file. 
Later I would want to read the file, get the char, use ord(), get the int, and then the bits that I entered, with the leading 0s.

Comment: You want the result to be a string?

Comment: Why do you want to preserve leading zeroes?

Comment: @thefourtheye I would want it to be a character but if the int doesn't save the leading 0 neither would chr(), i think

Comment: So u want to convert a binary string to a decimal string without losing the leading 0s?

Comment: @Alik I want to write in a file the characters from that int and later go get them and get the same bit i wrote, with the leading 0s. I will add that to the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve the number of initial zeroes by finding the first index of `1` (as it is a binary string).

```
>>> s = '0000001'
>>> '{}{}'.format('0'*s.index('1'),int(s,2))
'0000001'
>>> s = '0000011'
>>> '{}{}'.format('0'*s.index('1'),int(s,2))
'000003'
```

As you can see, only the leading zeroes are preserved and not the number of digits.

Another implementation (only zeroes included)

```
>>> def change(s):
...      try:
...           return '{}{}'.format('0'*s.index('1'),int(s,2))
...      except ValueError:
...           return s
... 
>>> change('000000')
'000000'
>>> change('000001')
'000001'
>>> change('000011')
'00003'
```

Comment: Do tell me the reason for the downvote. I will gladly make amends

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your use case, but the following would pretty much do its job for what you are looking for

**Implementation**

```
def weird_format(n):
    if not int(n, 2): return n
    return "{{:0{}}}".format(len(n) - len(n.lstrip('0')) + 1).format(int(n,2))
```

**Output**

```
>>> weird_format('000001')
'000001'
>>> weird_format('000101')
'0005'
>>> weird_format('11')
'3'
>>> weird_format('0000')
'0000'
```

Comment: Can you try with `weird_format('0000')` ... One of the base cases

Comment: @BhargavRao: Sure, edge case handling was missing. Feel free to think more edge cases.

Comment: @BhargavRao`ìf not int(n,2): ...` does not work as intended. The int() function raise the exception `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base ..`in case it can't convert n.

Comment: @GiovanniLombardo Yep. The reason why I used Exception handling in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29948969/4099593)

Answer (score 0):

An OOP oriented solution to your problem could be to create a `Binary` class which stores the information about the leading zeroes.

```
class Binary(object):

    def __init__(self, strval):
        object.__init__(self)
        self._leading_zeroes = 0
        self._int_repr = 0
        self._str_val = strval
        self._toBinary()

    def _toBinary(self):
        for c in self._str_val:
            if c=='0': self._leading_zeroes += 1
            else: break

        try: self._int_repr = int(self._str_val,2)
        except ValueError as e: raise e

    def GetLeadingZeroes(self):
        return ''.join(['0' for i in xrange(self._leading_zeroes)])

    def GetIntRepr(self):
        return self._int_repr

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__unicode__()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s%s' % (self.GetLeadingZeroes(), '' if self.GetIntRepr()==0 else '{0:b}'.format(self.GetIntRepr()))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.__str__())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b0 = Binary('000001')
    b1 = Binary('000000')
    b2 = Binary('001001')
    print b0, b1, b2

#output: 0000001 0000000 0001001
```

Then, if you need to perform operations on Binary objects. you could simply overload the operators of the Binary class.